# Have argparse collect, but not respond to, flags

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script which takes in some arguments, uses some of those argument to choose a script to run, and passes the rest of the arguments to that script. So it looks something like this:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('script', choices['a', 'b'])
parser.add_argument('rest_args', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.script == 'a':
    subprocess.call('python a.py %s' % ' '.join(args.rest_args))
else:
    subprocess.call('python b.py %s' % ' '.join(args.rest_args))
```

This works fine, unless I want to pass in arguments that start with `-`. For example, if I called `python my_script.py a --foo`, I'd get an error `unrecognized arguments`, when really I want to just have it run `python a.py --foo` (i.e. just pass the `--foo` along to the subprocess).

Is there a way to get around this with `argparse`?

Comment: What is foo? Is it the arg name or a value you want to store into rest_args?

Comment: I want it to be stored in `rest_args`.

Comment: argparse, when it faces a - or --, is looking in your args definition, for any optional arg having foo as name. I don't believe this is possible and to be honest this is not logical. None of the unix commands take a value with -- prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [parse_known_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args). It will parse all the options it recognizes, and returns all the unrecognized arguments in `unknown`:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('script', choices=['a', 'b'])

args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args(['a', '--foo'])

print(args)
# Namespace(script='a')
print(unknown)
# ['--foo']
```

Comment: I just posted this exact thing as a solution! I'll give you the check though :)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the function `parse_known_args`, which provides a solution to this, albeit perhaps not ideal.

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('script', choices['a', 'b'])
args, rest_args = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.script == 'a':
    subprocess.call('python a.py %s' % ' '.join(rest_args))
else:
    subprocess.call('python b.py %s' % ' '.join(rest_args))
```

What this does is use `parse_known_args` to parse what's known, and collect the rest in a list. Then those remaining arguments can be passed to the subprocess as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The `'*'` works if you include `'--'` in the argument list:

```
1502:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack26264831.py a -- --foo bar
Namespace(rest_args=['--foo', 'bar'], script='a')
```

An alternative is to use `REMAINDER` ('...') instead of '*':

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('script', choices=['a', 'b'])
parser.add_argument('rest_args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args

1500:~/mypy$ python2.7 stack26264831.py a --foo bar
Namespace(rest_args=['--foo', 'bar'], script='a')
```

Both the '--' and REMAINDER mean: 'treat what follows as positional arguments'.

`parse_known_args` also works, though its logic is different - 'just return a list of the strings you didn't recognize'.  `parse_args` calls `parse_known_args` and raises an error is the `rest` value is not empty.

---

But don't use `REMAINDER` as the first positional argument:  [Using argparse.REMAINDER at beginning of parser / sub parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43219022/using-argparse-remainder-at-beginning-of-parser-sub-parser)