# Using argparse.REMAINDER at beginning of parser / sub parser

Tags: python, argparse

I want to implement an arg parser that allows me to run unittests as one of the sub commands, blindly passing the arguments on to unittest.main().  e.g.,

```
$ foo.py unittest [args to pass to unittest.main()]
```

along with other sub commands:

```
$ foo.py foo ...
$ foo.py bar ...
```

Following argparse's example, this works:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
import argparse                                                                 

p = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')                                        
p.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')                          
sub = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')                                              
foo = sub.add_parser('foo')                                                     
bar = sub.add_parser('bar')                                                     
unittest = sub.add_parser('unittest')                                           
unittest.add_argument('command') # Need to add this to make it work.                                              
unittest.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)                         

print(p.parse_args('unittest command -blah blah'.split()))
```

Output:

```
Namespace(args=['-blah', 'blah'], cmd='unittest', command='command', verbose=False)
```

But this doesn't.  It seems to require a "normal" argument first:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
import argparse                                                                 

p = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')                                        
p.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')                          
sub = p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')                                              
foo = sub.add_parser('foo')                                                     
bar = sub.add_parser('bar')                                                     
unittest = sub.add_parser('unittest')                                           
unittest.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)                         

print(p.parse_args('unittest -blah blah'.split()))
```

Output:

```
$ /tmp/foo.py    
usage: PROG [-h] [-v] {foo,bar,unittest} ...
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: -blah
```

I *can* do `print(p.parse_args('unittest -- -f -g'.split()))`, but requiring `--` kind of defeats the purpose of argparse.REMAINDER.

Is there a way to get `argparse` to do what I want?  Or do I just need to hand parse this case?

Python 2.7.5

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree here.  Keep the test code out of the library code, entirely.

Comment: It's a standalone script that I need to make sure is easily testable in case anyone else modifies it.  An external test harness doesn't accomplish that...

Comment: The fact that this particular use case is testing is irrelevant. There are plenty of other situations where the same issue arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the same issue discussed in http://bugs.python.org/issue17050, `argparse.REMAINDER doesn't work as first argument`

My deduction from 4 years ago still holds - the `-blah` is being classed as an optional's flag even before `REMAINDER` has a chance to act.  '--' is parsed earlier, but `...` is, in a sense just a generalization of '*'.  And not a widely used one.  For what it's worth the 'subparsers' Action has a `nargs='+...'` value (`argparse.PARSER`) - it's like REMAINDER except it requires at least one string, the 'cmd'.

The possible fix in http://bugs.python.org/issue9334 has not been acted on.  So you either need to handle the '-blah' by itself, or use '--'.  `parse_known_args` might also work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, the existing behavior is bad. One workaround is to implement a simple
`ArgumentParser` subclass and use that for your subparser:

```
class SubcommandParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    """This subparser puts all remaining arguments in args attribute of namespace"""
    def parse_known_args(self, args=None, namespace=None):
        if namespace is None:
            namespace = argparse.Namespace()
        setattr(namespace, 'args', args)
        return namespace, []

...

p.add_subparsers(dest='cmd', parser_class=SubcommandParser)
```