# How to make argparse take other parameters as arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a wrapper script which passes some arguments on to another application. Calling `wrapper.py --param1 x --param2 y --args -i 1 -name "Mike Wazowski" --verbose` should in the end initiate a `subprocess.Popen` which finally executes:

```
app.exe -i 1 -n "Mike Wazowski" --verbose
```

However, this does not work, since argparse in my wrapper.py script believes `-i`, `-n` and `--verbose` are parameters it should parse.

I could encapsulate the arguments I merely wish to pass on in quotation marks, but then I'd also have to escape any quotation marks within quotation marks  would. However, I wish to *really* avoid this:

```
`wrapper.py --param1 x --param2 y --args "-i 1 -name \"Mike Wazowski\" --verbose"`
```

---

#### What I have tried already

I'm taking [this example](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#nargs) from the documentation:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*')
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='*')
>>> parser.add_argument('baz', nargs='*')
>>> parser.parse_args('a b --foo x y --bar 1 2'.split())
Namespace(bar=['1', '2'], baz=['a', 'b'], foo=['x', 'y'])
```

But instead of giving it `--bar 1 2` I need to be able to provide e.g. `--bar -i -n "Mike Wazowski" --verbose`. This, however, will result in an error:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*')
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo -s 1 -e 2'.split())
usage: [-h] [--foo [FOO [FOO ...]]]
: error: unrecognized arguments: -i -n "Mike Wazowski" --verbose
```

What could I do to make this work?
I'm fine by always having to define my `--args` parameter as the last parameter. Should I just treat `--args` as a dummy parameter and then parse `sys.argv` manually to fetch what I need? If so, how can tell argparse to ignore everything happening after the occurance of `--args` in my wrapper command?

Comment: You could quote them properly: `--args "-i 1 -name \"Mike Wazowski\" --verbose"`. Why do you want to avoid that? It's the correct way to handle it.

Comment: My problem is that I need to pass on the arguments as-is. They are not escaped like that to begin with, and I'd have to make recursive escaping of quotation marks within quotation marks. I figured it would be easier to just try to pass the parameters on as they are rather than recursively alter the arguments.

Comment: I guess, what I'm trying to say is... imagine someone already quoted and escaped their arguments the way you did. I need to take that in and pass that on.

Comment: "as-is" and "as they are" *where*, though? Are you just copying and pasting them from something into your terminal?

Comment: No. The arguments are being generated by programs, executed by users. These arguments could also be hand-written by users who do not know they need to quote or escape. I figured there were two approaches to solve this; one were to parse the given arguments and add escaping where needed, the other entailed just passing the args on "as they were". Since I'm also dealing with display issues of escaped characters in the user-facing application down the line, I'm opting for just passing args on.

Comment: So this is wrapping another program and is itself wrapped by a third one? I think you're solving an XY problem: why is this communication all being done via command line arguments?

Comment: `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` can be used to accept all remaining strings as arguments.  `--` can also be used that way.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264831/have-argparse-collect-but-not-respond-to-flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, hpaulj! I think that `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER` is my best option here, as it separates the target appication's arguments from my wrapper's arguments. This way I don't have to worry about that the wrapper's arguments clash with the arguments I merely wish to pass on.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('rest_args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

So when calling `wrapper.py -- -i 1 -name "Mike Wazowski" --verbose` I get:

```
Namespace(rest_args=['-i', '1', '-name', 'Mike Wazowski', '--verbose'], verbose=False)
```

And if calling `wrapper.py --verbose -- -i 1 -name "Mike Wazowski" --verbose` I get:

```
Namespace(rest_args=['-i', '1', '-name', 'Mike Wazowski', '--verbose'], verbose=True)
```

Note, the `--` is actually optional in the above examples and will yield the same results.